# Application not support for Different types of screens

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to make an application that supports Different types of phone screens and I tried this way.
Note ? that I have modified every folder(small,m,l,xl) that supports a device inside the interface, but nothing appears in the application on different devices in terms of size and dimensions.

[image]

Comment: Please check if you have added `<supports-screens android:resizable="true"
                        android:smallScreens="true"
                        android:normalScreens="true"
                        android:largeScreens="true" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: yes , i add android:xlargeScreens="true" also  .  Are all files in layout added to diffrent screen ?

Comment: You can use `DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
            var dpi = dm.DensityDpi;//screen Density
            float de= dm.Density;` code to get your device screen density, if you get the small dpi, you will get the layout from `layout-small` in the device

Comment: hi. Has this code been added to all interfaces activity in OnCreate?

Comment: Above code just add the MainAcitivity to check your device screen density, For example, if you device screen density is smaller than 1, device will display the `layout-small` layout.